# Getting started with the forge configurator inventor sample

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to run the sample application found at Autodesks git repository:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor

Trying to follow the steps outlined, but fail miserably, when trying to build and run locally.
Does anyone know of a more detailed getting started guide.

When i reach the point in the guide where it says run `dotnet run initialize=true`

I get this `[13:38:51 WRN] Cannot create OSS bucket. Repeating` a couple of times and then it throws this:

```
[13:39:23 FTL] Application startup exception
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (App Bundle package is not found (AppBundles/DataCheckerPlugin.bundle.zip))
 ---> System.Exception: App Bundle package is not found (AppBundles/DataCheckerPlugin.bundle.zip)
   at WebApplication.Processing.Publisher.PostAppBundleAsync(String packagePathname, ForgeAppBase config) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Processing\Publisher.cs:line 172
   at WebApplication.Processing.Publisher.InitializeAsync(String packagePathname, ForgeAppBase config) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Processing\Publisher.cs:line 243
   at WebApplication.Processing.ForgeAppBase.InitializeAsync(String packagePathname) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Processing\ForgeAppBase.cs:line 110
   at WebApplication.Processing.FdaClient.InitializeAsync() in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Processing\FdaClient.cs:line 51
   at WebApplication.Initializer.InitializeAsync() in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Initializer.cs:line 90
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at WebApplication.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Initializer initializer, ILogger`1 logger, LocalCache localCache, IOptions`1 forgeConfiguration, Publisher publisher) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Startup.cs:line 81
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (App Bundle package is not found (AppBundles/DataCheckerPlugin.bundle.zip))
 ---> System.Exception: App Bundle package is not found (AppBundles/DataCheckerPlugin.bundle.zip)
   at WebApplication.Processing.Publisher.PostAppBundleAsync(String packagePathname, ForgeAppBase config) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Processing\Publisher.cs:line 172
   at WebApplication.Processing.Publisher.InitializeAsync(String packagePathname, ForgeAppBase config) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Processing\Publisher.cs:line 243
   at WebApplication.Processing.ForgeAppBase.InitializeAsync(String packagePathname) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Processing\ForgeAppBase.cs:line 110
   at WebApplication.Processing.FdaClient.InitializeAsync() in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Processing\FdaClient.cs:line 51
   at WebApplication.Initializer.InitializeAsync() in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Initializer.cs:line 90
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at WebApplication.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Initializer initializer, ILogger`1 logger, LocalCache localCache, IOptions`1 forgeConfiguration, Publisher publisher) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Startup.cs:line 81
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at WebApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication\Program.cs:line 34
PS D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\6\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication>
```

This project might be beyond the scope of my skills, but it would be nice to at least get the demo up and running - before we just dismiss it and go hire somebody to do it for us.

Appreciate any input.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real issue is the missing **DataCheckerPlugin.bundle.zip** file as the 2 exceptions show. Make sure it's available here:
[image]

I did not have **.NET 4.7** installed, so the project's target framework reverted to **4.6** and in that case, it could not be compiled. Just change it to a **4.7** based version (in my case it's **4.7.2**) and build the project again:
[image]